# Why do we need to bind this pointer to a member function in boost::bind?

Tags: boost, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I noticed in many `boost::bind` applications, for example [here](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/SimpleActionServer%28ExecuteCallbackMethod%29), we need to bind `this pointer` to a member function.

What does that do?

Thanks,
Rico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361576/why-do-we-need-to-bind-this-pointer-to-a-member-function-in-boost::bind?/) by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@RicoJ This question is not really related to ROS and you may want to search or ask in other forums like [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but I will answer your question.

`boost::bind` is a special function used to create a functor for you with the arguments you pass to it. So, it basically creates a new function with the arguments; the problem here is that, if you want to bind a member function you really need to pass, apart from the special placeholders : _1, _2, that store the function arguments, the reference to the object context, that is the special word `this`.

So the first argument is the reference to the member function, the second, the context of the object itself and then the arguments. If you do not supply the context, the function itself cannot be defined properly within the member scope.

Hope that solve your question.

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2